# Use of lists for collecting items

Tags: python, list

I'm currently going through the book "Learning Python The Hard Way", and I'm trying to make a simple game. In this game, I want to be able to pick up at item "Flashlight" in one room, to be able to get into another room. I can, however, not make it work :-(

So the question is, how do I carry the same list through several functions, and how do I put things in it? I want to be able to put multiple things in it.

I tried to call the pick() function within it self, but keep getting a "TypeERROR: 'str' is not callable, though I am providing my function with a list?

Hope you can help me out, thanks :-)

Code:

```
def start(bag):
        print "You have entered a dark room"
        print "You can only see one door"
        print "Do you want to enter?"

        answer = raw_input(">")

        if answer == "yes":
            light_room(bag)
        elif answer == "no":
            print "You descidede to go home and cry!"
            exit()
        else:
            dead("That is not how we play!")

def light_room(bag):
    print "WOW, this room is amazing! You see magazines, cans of ass and a flashlight"
    print "What do you pick up?"
    print "1. Magazine"
    print "2. Cans of ass"
    print "3. Flashlight"

    pick(bag)

def pick(bag):    
    pick = raw_input(">")

    if int(pick) == 1:
        bag.append("Magazine")
        print "Your bag now contains: \n %r \n" % bag
    elif int(pick) == 2:
        bag.append("Can of ass")
        print "Your bag now contains: \n %r \n" % bag
    elif int(pick) == 3:
        bag.append("Flashlight")
        print "Your bag now contains: \n %r \n" % bag                    
    else:
        print "You are dead!"
        exit()

def start_bag(bag):
    if "flashlight" in bag:
        print "You have entered a dark room"
        print "But your flashlight allows you to see a secret door"
        print "Do you want to enter the 'secret' door og the 'same' door as before?"

        answer = raw_input(">")

        if answer == "secret":
            secret_room()
        elif answer == "same":
            dead("A rock hit your face!")
        else:
            print "Just doing your own thing! You got lost and died!"
            exit()
    else:
        start(bag)

def secret_room():
    print "Exciting!"
    exit() 

def dead(why):
    print why, "You suck!"
    exit()

bag = []
start(bag)
```

Comment: The full TraceBack would be useful here.

Comment: I removed the `loops` tag from this question since you don't actually have a loop, but you probably want one. Even without redefining `pick` within itself, recursion probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried to call the pick() function within it self, but keep getting a "TypeERROR: 'str' is not callable, though I am providing my function with a list?

The problem here is that in this line:

```
def pick(bag):    
    pick = raw_input(">")
```

you bind `pick` to a new value (a str) so it doesn't reference a function anymore. Change that to something like:

```
def pick(bag):    
    picked = raw_input(">")
```